# Security filter configuration not working after upgrade to Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm upgrading from Spring Boot 2.7.5 to 3.0.11, and with that there are several changes in `SecurityFilter` configurations. I'm able to convert my existing filter class to Spring Boot 3.x specifics however, I'm getting the below error while running the app:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource
> [.../configuration/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate
> [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method
> 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Web security configuration
> error: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC
> patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use
> requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use
> requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).
>
> This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your
> servlet context:
> {org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/],
> org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet=[/h2-console/*]}.

This is my config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- Swagger UI v2
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "v2/api-docs",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "swagger-ui.html",
            "webjars/**",
            // -- Swagger UI v3
            "/api/template/v3/api-docs/**",
            "v3/api-docs/**",
            "/api/template/swagger-ui/**",
            "swagger-ui/**",
            // Actuators
            "/actuator/**",
            "/health/**"
    };

    /**
     * Configures access to application with reduced requirements to security
     * to allow local testing and h2 console.
     *
     * @param http security object
     * @return instance of {@link SecurityFilterChain}
     */
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        try {
            http
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                            .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                    .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) // disables pop-up
                    .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer
                                    .frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin)) // to make accessible h2 console, disables xframe deny warnings
                    .cors(); // uses cors settings - only disabled if WebConfigLocal running
            return http.build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new GenericRuntimeException(buildMessage(ERROR_WEB_SECURITY_FILTER.getText(ex.getMessage())), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help understand what went wrong? I'm not able to understand anything from the error.

Comment: How does you pom.xml look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Spring Security version 6.x it is no longer possible to demand the [MvcRequestMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/servlet/util/matcher/MvcRequestMatcher.html) fluently. Instead, the desired patterns are passed to a general `#requestMatchers` method, which by default uses [MvcRequestMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/servlet/util/matcher/MvcRequestMatcher.html) for mapping behind the scenes. [AntPathRequestMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html) must now be explicitly passed to this `#requestMatchers` method if necessary.

A discovered security vulnerability [CVE-2023-34035](https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34035) shows that if more than one mappable servlet is secured by Spring Security, misconfigurations can occur. Therefore, as of version 6.1.2, in such a case of two servlets, the [RequestMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html) must be specified explicitly.

That is what seems to be your problem. For example, the `H2` database places its own dedicated [JakartaWebServlet](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/main/org/h2/server/web/JakartaWebServlet.java) in the context for its endpoint, what forces us to explicitly specify [MvcRequestMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/servlet/util/matcher/MvcRequestMatcher.html) for all endpoints handled by Spring's [DispatcherServlet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html).

As explained here [cve-2023-34035-mitigations](https://github.com/jzheaux/cve-2023-34035-mitigations) you can do as follows:

1. provide the following `bean`:

```java
@Bean
public MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc(HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) {
    return new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
}
```

2. adapt your filter chain:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc, HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    try {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(AUTH_WHITELIST)).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) // disables pop-up
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer
                                .frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin)) // to make accessible h2 console, disables xframe deny warnings
                .cors(); // uses cors settings - only disabled if WebConfigLocal running
        return http.build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new GenericRuntimeException(buildMessage(ERROR_WEB_SECURITY_FILTER.getText(ex.getMessage())), ex);
    }
}
```

If this won't fix your problem you might wanna set up a dedicated filter chain for the `H2` db as well, however I don't think that this would be necessary.

Comment: There is a compilation error in: 
`.requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(AUTH_WHITELIST)).permitAll()`. It only accepts `String` instead of `String[]`

Comment: nevermind, i was able to get around it :) app is running now. thanks a ton.